# AddEventListener with mouseover to hide paragraph

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to understand addEventListener and using the mouseover ablity to hide a paragraph when someone hovers over a button. I am not getting any errors in the chrome developer so I am not sure what I am missing. What am I missing?

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction);
document.addEventListener("mouseover", myThirdFunction);

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("sun").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function myThirdFunction() {
  document.getElementById("sun").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<!-- You should:1. Rover over the below button and make the paragraph below 
    it disappear. -->
<input type="button" value="Roll Over Me" class="rollOverMe" />
<p id="sun"> This paragraph will burn from the heat of the sun!</p>
```

I'm expecting to see that whenever the user mouse hovers over the button that the p id="sun" is not visible.

Comment: 1. You need to add the listener to the button, not the document. 2. you need to move the script below the button, best right before `</body>`

Comment: Also, try to help us (and your future self) by using meaningful function names. Call a function by using a name that gives a clue about what this function is used for.

Comment: @ChrisG Ok, i'll be honest I am using w3School site to learn this stuff.(https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp). On that note would it look something like giving the button an id and then doing a buttonID.getelementByid("buttonID").style.Visibility = "hidden"; or am i totally off.

Comment: You mixed stuff up: `getElementById` is a function provided by the `document` object; it returns the element with the stated id. So you'd use `var theButton = document.getElementId('roll_button');`, and once you have the button, you add the listener to it: `theButton.addEventListener(...);` Or you do what they did on w3schools and chain the functions calls: `document.getElementId('roll_button').addEventListener(...);` (btw, w3schools has its issues and I recommend not using it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't repeat document.getElementByIds in your page too much. It is okay for small apps - for practicing and for learning. Too many references/pickups from the DOM slows down performance.
2. As mentioned, try giving meaningful function names.
3. There are multiple mouse event listeners. To achieve what you are expecting, we need to use mouseleave and mouseover together.

```js
var buttonElement = document.getElementById("tooltip-btn");
var paragraph = document.getElementById("sun");

function myFunction() {
  paragraph.style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function myThirdFunction() {
  paragraph.style.visibility = "visible";
}

buttonElement.addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction);
buttonElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", myThirdFunction);
```

```html
<input id="tooltip-btn" type="button" value="Roll Over Me" class="rollOverMe" />
<p id="sun"> This paragraph will burn from the heat of the sun!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple issue and as you are starting out, I hope this helps.

Personally, I would stop using W3School and start using MDN. The [MDN Tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Tutorials) are a good start.

As to your issue, there was a fair bit wrong. Something like the following is a basic structure for a lot of common scenarios.

```js
function paraHide(e) {
  var d = document.getElementById("sun");
  d.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
function paraShow(e) {
  var d = document.getElementById("sun");
  d.style.visibility = "visible";
}
/*
  window.onload means wait until the HTML has loaded, then
  automatically start the following JavaScript
*/
window.onload = function() {
  // get all elements with the class "rollOverMe"
  var d = document.querySelectorAll(".rollOverMe");
  // if any elements found, continue
  if (d) {
    var i, max = d.length;
    // for each found element, add the following
    // Event Lsiteners
    for(i=0;i<max;i++) {
      d[i].addEventListener("mouseover",paraHide,false)
      d[i].addEventListener("mouseout",paraShow,false)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Roll Over Me" class="rollOverMe" />
<p id="sun"> This paragraph will burn from the heat of the sun!</p>
<input type="button" value="Over me too!" class="rollOverMe" />
```